# Disable direct push and allow Gerrit push

Tags: gerrit

Need to configure the Gerrit with below conditions

Dissable the direct push to GIT

Allow only push through GERRIT

Is this configuration can be done on gerrit?

Regards,
Venkatesh

Comment: That's the typical use case. Please read [the manual](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#example_roles).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Projects > List >  > Access
2. To "Dissable the direct push to GIT"

Do NOT set "ALLOW" permission or set "DENY" one to "refs/heads/*" reference

3. To "Allow push through GERRIT"

Set "ALLOW" permission to "refs/for/refs/*" reference